# How to build a x64 and x86 executable at the same time

Tags: c#, x86, nuget, 64-bit

In dotnet core/.net 5 is there the possibility to have a project that builds executable for x86 and x64?

An obvious option would be to work with two separate project files as suggested here: [Build both x86 and x64 at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359582/build-both-x86-and-x64-at).

Is there an alternative? Neither `<PlatformTargets>x64;x86</PlatformTargets>` nor `<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x86;win-x64</RuntimeIdentifiers>` in .csproj file yield the desired result. I even tried with a publish-profile using`<RuntimeIdentifiers>win-x64;win-x86</RuntimeIdentifiers>` which seems not to have the desired effect.

I would like to have both files as native items in the nuget package so I think it would be nice if I could do everything with just one project.

**Update**: I cannot use AnyCPU because it might be shipped as 32-bit bundle together with 32-bit native libraries. The AnyCPU might run as 64-bit then (there is no constraint the JIT could detect) and be incompatible with the native files and fail as a consequence.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/516730/what-does-the-visual-studio-any-cpu-target-mean ?

Comment: I updated the question to explain why I cannot use AnyCPU.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to build with 2 build scripts, then you can specify the "PlatformTargets" separately.